# Simplest way to redraw a matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am struggling to setup a simple code snippet for redrawing a matplotlib plot.

I am using this code:

```
# initialization of figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

for x in range(5):
    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(x)
    if x == 0:
        plt.show()
    else:
        plt.draw  # or fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.clf()
```

The plot get's only created when I use plt.show(), but when I use the plt.draw function the plot just freezes.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing paretheses after plt.draw, so you are not actually calling the method.

Should be:

```
plt.draw()
```

Comment: Although from your code I can't see what you are expecting to plot. It currently just plots a blank canvas. If you need more help with this please upload a more complete example.